# Isolation Forest Prediction

Tags: python

To compute anomaly score we use whole dataset to test or only test dataset? Can someone please help.
And with streaming data we doesn't train so in that we are using whole dataset to find accuracy. So how would we compare both without streaming and with streaming.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The training dataset is only used to fit/train the model. The training will extract information from your training data and store it in your model so after training you no longer need it. You should never include training data when you later check the performance/accuracy of your model, that is only the test set.

For predictions and computation of anomaly scores you only need to use the dataset you actually want to check for anomalies/outliers.

For streaming you should train first on offline data which only contains inliers or has a know ratio of outliers. Once it is trained you can use it to make predictions on new streamed data without comparing to your offline data.

Comment: The streaming trained data would be same as the normal trained data and normal test data would be used as streaming in streaming evaluation?

Comment: Why so? The streamed model can be trained if it contain anomaly right?

Comment: You can train with anomalies, but then you are expected to know what percentage of your data is anomalies. In sklearn this is called the contamination.

Comment: And two more questions, 1. While Working for streaming data, the model is not initially trained, and maintained dynamically? 2. Can Streaming Model which is dynamically updated can give better prediction accuracy then trained model?

Comment: 1. When using streaming data you can either train it initially on offline data and then retrain using streaming data or you can use the initial streaming data as training data. But your model will not be able to make predictions until it is trained.

Comment: 2. It can give better results since data tends to change over time and it helps keep your model from degrading. It also might give worse results since you run the risk of retraining on anomalous data.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot Simon :)

Comment: @SimonLarsson Thanks for your answer. May I ask you kindly to have a look at related post [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/90720/incorrect-results-of-isolationforest)?